# What's the difference between LastCall and Expect.Call?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

Can some explain when I should use the Rhino Mocks LastCall and when I should use Expect.Call. 
I gathered that Expect.Call  is just LastCall in a wrapper.  Also I assume that Expect.Call should be used when dealing with return values in Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (mocks.Record())
{
    myMock.AVeryMeaningFullMethodThatDoesNotReturnAValue("a to be ignored parameter");
    LastCall.IgnoreArguments();

    Expect.Call(myMock.AnotherMethodThatDoesReturnAValue()).IgnoreArguments().Returns("barney");
}
```

First a bit of introduction. In `Record` mode, you can specify the behavior of your "mocked" environment. You can do this, but just specifying the methods you are expecting:

```
myMock.AVeryMeaningFullMethodThatDoesNotReturnAValue("a to be ignored parameter");
```

Or, you can do this via the Mocking framework:

```
Expect.Call(myMock.Do("stuff")).Return("something");
```

In the first case, you can't call the methods of the Rhino mocking framework, because the mocked method does not return a value. The `Expect.Call()` demands a return type. In order to allow you as programmer to specify Rhino mock behaviour (e.g. `IgnoreArguments()`) they provide a static class `LastCall`.

That way you can still `IgnoreArguments` on a void method. Or specify that you expect it to repeat many times (`LastCall.Repeat.Any()`).

Comment: Could explain briefly when to use each or are they the same thing essentially?